# Installing seaborn on Docker Alpine

Tags: numpy, docker, seaborn, alpine-linux

I am trying to install `seaborn` with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --update python py-pip python-dev 

RUN pip install seaborn

CMD python
```

The error I get is related to `numpy` and `scipy` (required by `seaborn`). It starts with:

> /tmp/easy_install-nvj61E/numpy-1.11.1/setup.py:327: UserWarning:
> Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython
> sources and expanding templates

and ends with

> File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 654, in get_mathlib_info
>
> RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-DZ4cXr/scipy/
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c pip install seaborn' returned a non-zero code: 1

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To fix this error, you need to install `gcc`: `apk add gcc`.

But you will see that you will hit a new error as numpy, matplotlip and scipy have several dependencies. You need to also install `gfortran`, `musl-dev`, `freetype-dev`, etc.

Here is a Dockerfile based on you initial one that will install those dependencies as well as `seaborn`:

```
FROM alpine:latest

# install dependencies
# the lapack package is only in the community repository
RUN echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk --update add --no-cache \ 
    lapack-dev \ 
    gcc \
    freetype-dev

RUN apk add python py-pip python-dev 

# Install dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    gfortran \
    musl-dev \
    g++
RUN ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h

RUN pip install seaborn

# removing dependencies
RUN apk del .build-deps

CMD python
```

You'll notice that I'm removing the dependencies using `apk-del .build-deps` to limit the size of your image (http://www.sandtable.com/reduce-docker-image-sizes-using-alpine/).

Personally I also had to install ca-certificates but it seems you didn't have this issue.

*Note*: You could also build your image FROM the `python:2.7-alpine` image to avoid installing python and pip yourself.

Comment: Fantastic, that worked. It took forever to build the container but finally it completed (weighs in at 693.3 MB). Thanks for a great answer (solved my problem and also taught me something about Docker best-practice).

Comment: @emh You're welcome. I also have to build images containing scipy and I confirm they take ages to build from scratch. It's also difficult to keep them small. At least they are smaller than Ubuntu-based images!

Comment: I couldn't find `lapack-dev` in the testing repository ATM (using `python:alpine` docker image alias for `python:3.6-alpine`), so I needed to use http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community  to get the `lapack-dev` package

Comment: @shadi You're right, the package moved to the community repository, I'll update the answer

Comment: Recently `numpy` was updated and compilation fails. As written [here](https://gist.github.com/orenitamar/f29fb15db3b0d13178c1c4dd611adce2) you can do `pip install numpy==1.14.3`, but then beware that if you start installing also `pandas` then it will try to bring the latest version of `numpy` again.