# Running Python and Java in Docker

Tags: java, python, windows, shell, docker

I have a docker image with installed python and java, and now I want to run both processes as child processes of docker.

I have checked this post which explains how to **prepare** image with docker and python installed. It does not explain how to get both of them running.
[How to run Docker with python and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51121875/how-to-run-docker-with-python-and-java)

I checked how to run multiple processes in docker
https://runnable.com/docker/rails/run-multiple-processes-in-a-container

I know it is a **bad thing** to run multiple processes in one container. It is an urgency and limitation, so I will stick to it for some time.

So docker documentation (above) says, prepare a shell file which starts two processes and run it inside docker file.

However!!! I connected to my docker from host command line (`docker exec -it container_name bash`). I saw (`top`) running processes. There is Java process running and python process is not running.

My *Dockerfile*

```
# Prepare slim python, and install open-jdk-11
ENTRYPOINT ./startJavaAndPython.sh
```

*startJavaAndPython.sh*

```
java -XX:+UseContainerSupport $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar java-app.jar;
python app.py;
```

I also read https://askubuntu.com/questions/287350/start-a-new-process-without-blocking-the-terminal
and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152310/how-to-correctly-start-an-application-from-a-shell/305769, which did not work in my case. Because as you see, in my shell, if a command does not end with `;`, there will be errors when I start docker.

### Updates

1) 
So, ampersands do not help.

`startJavaAndPython.sh`

```
java -XX:+UseContainerSupport $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar java-app.jar &;
python app.py &;
```

I also tried, but it did not work.
*startJavaAndPython.sh*

```
java -XX:+UseContainerSupport $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar java-app.jar &
python app.py &
```

I received

```
$ docker run my-composed-task
: not foundonJava.sh: 1: ./startJavaAndPython.sh:
: not startJavaAndPython.sh: 2: ./startJavaAndPython.sh:
```

2) I can start my docker container, connect to it ssh, and run the python app manually. It will work!!! But how to do it automatically, without hands!

3) I use **Windows 10** as a host machine.

I used these links, which  might be helpful for others.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/287350/start-a-new-process-without-blocking-the-terminal

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152310/how-to-correctly-start-an-application-from-a-shell/305769

[How do I get into a Docker container's shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-do-i-get-into-a-docker-containers-shell)

Comment: And if you connect to the container and type the command to start the python script manually? Do you get an error or is the process starting?

Comment: No! I ssh my docker, and started python app manually. it worked!!!

Comment: Is the python process depending on the java process? If so it is possible that when the python starts the java program has not yet started and so you have a failure

Comment: Why do you need to end commands with a semicolon? I've never seen that before. Can you not run your entrypoint script with bash?

Comment: No, python process is an independent app. it knows nothing about java (at this moment)

Comment: So both of your java and python processes run for the lifetime of the container?

Comment: Yes, Java runs after the container has started. To get running python - I have to do it manually via ssh.

Answer (score 1):

After much pain. As I said, I use **Windows**. It does append `\r` at the end of each line. Then my shell script has these endings and fails to start. More exactly, it starts first command - which is to start java, but it never executes the second command, which starts python.

**startJavaAndPython.sh**

```
java -XX:+UseContainerSupport $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar sidecarForPythonService-app.jar & python app.py;
```

If you have other details, feel free to answer.