# Installing Java in Google App Engine with Python runtime

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

I am new to the Google App Engine. 
I created a new project with a python runtime and used Flask to expose some API endpoints. One of the methods uses a python library(tabula-py) which has dependency on Java (8+). 
When I ran locally everything worked but, this is failing after deploying to gcloud. Any tips on setting up Java in the App Engine? I can't install it through the requirements.txt

Thanks a lot!

Regards,
Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE runs your apps in containers that by default only have the runtime that you specify in the `app.yaml`. However, you can [set a custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build) with Python and Java to run your application with.

In order to do so you must use the **GAE Flexible** environment and define something like the following in the `Dockerfile`:

```
### 1. Get Linux
FROM alpine:3.7

### 2. Get Java via the package manager
RUN apk update \
&& apk upgrade \
&& apk add --no-cache bash \
&& apk add --no-cache --virtual=build-dependencies unzip \
&& apk add --no-cache curl \
&& apk add --no-cache openjdk8-jre

### 3. Get Python, PIP

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 \
&& python3 -m ensurepip \
&& pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools \
&& rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi && \
if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; fi && \
rm -r /root/.cache

ENV FLASK_APP main.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT 8080
### Get Flask for the app
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org flask

####
#### OPTIONAL : 4. SET JAVA_HOME environment variable, uncomment the line below if you need it

#ENV JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk"

####

EXPOSE 8080
ADD main.py /
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

I tested the custom runtime and it worked for me, but I wasn't able to test the tabula-py library because for some reason, the import fails in my environment (even locally). However, I believe it should work.

For reference, I based my `Dockerfile` on the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51121875/how-to-run-docker-with-python-and-java)

Comment: Hi Jose, Thank you very much. This helped setting my Java in the container.