# GAE deploy error :No module named 'tabula'

Tags: python, dockerfile, app-engine-flexible, tabula-py

At first I created a new project with a Python runtime and used Flask to expose some API endpoints. One of the methods uses a Python library (tabula-py) and
I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59925185/installing-java-in-google-app-engine-with-python-runtime) that because tabula-py requires Java8+,
I have to go for Flexible environment with custom run time.

And so I did, I made a Dockerfile (as shown below) but unfortunately, I still get this error while deploying the app to gcloud. I have to say that locally the code works perfectly but when I use "gcloud app deploy" I get this error.

```
Error: While importing "main", an ImportError was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
__import__(module_name)
File "/main.py", line 4, in <module>
import tabula
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabula'
```

> 

main.py

```
import tabula
.
.
.
df = tabula.read_pdf(str(latest_file), pages=1)  ## transforming into list of dataframes.
```

> 

app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
env_variables:
 FLASK_APP : 'main.py'
```

> 

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
RUN pip uninstall tabula && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir Flask pyvirtualdisplay python-environ Datetime && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir glob3 pandas-gbq pandas schedule && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir tabula-py beautifulsoup4 Datetime urllib3 && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir gunicorn Werkzeug && \
    pip install --upgrade pip --user && \
    pip3 uninstall -y tabula-py && \
    pip3 install tabula-py
    ### 1. Get Linux
FROM alpine:3.7

### 2. Get Java via the package manager
RUN apk update \
&& apk upgrade \
&& apk add --no-cache bash \
&& apk add --no-cache --virtual=build-dependencies unzip \
&& apk add --no-cache curl \
&& apk add --no-cache openjdk8-jre

### 3. Get Python, PIP

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 \
&& python3 -m ensurepip \
&& pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools \
&& rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi && \
if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; fi && \
rm -r /root/.cache

ENV FLASK_APP main.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT 8080
### Get Flask for the app
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org flask

####
#### OPTIONAL : 4. SET JAVA_HOME environment variable, uncomment the line below if you need it

#ENV JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk"

####

EXPOSE 8080
ADD main.py /
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you mentioned that you've created the Dockerfile so you can run your app on Flex environment. Where you able to build the Dockerfile on your local machine? Also, please move your other `pip` commands to after the `RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org flask`

Comment: i did not try to run it on my local machine.
but i figure it out! thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 2):

So it took me a while to figure out whats wrong.
but apperantly the order of the commands in the docker file is the problem.

```
FROM python:3
RUN pip uninstall tabula && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir Flask pyvirtualdisplay python-environ 
Datetime && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir glob3 pandas-gbq pandas schedule && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir tabula-py beautifulsoup4 Datetime 
urllib3 && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir gunicorn Werkzeug && \
    pip install --upgrade pip --user && \
    pip3 uninstall -y tabula-py && \
    pip3 install tabula-py
    ### 1. Get Linux
```

> 

at the first part iv' installed all the python libraries but right after,
i deleted all the python things that are installed ,

```
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 \
&& python3 -m ensurepip \
&& pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools \
&& rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi && \
if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 
/usr/bin/python; fi && \
rm -r /root/.cache
```

so the solution is to delete this part.